# Javascript forEach() is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ecmascript-6

So the function I am using here is simple (maybe not so much idk) all that is meant to happen is when an image is clicked on the page that has the class of .img it will open a modal to show a large view of the picture. simple right? well it works just fine in all browsers except IE (I hate IE already)

initially the code was built with an arrow function after googling I found that IE doesn't support arrow functions.. (why would it right?) so I simply changed the arrow function to just a function.. great works in other browsers... still not in IE.

```
   img.forEach((img) => {
    img.addEventListener('click', function mdl() {
     modal.style.display = 'block';
     modalImg.src = this.src;
   })
 })
```

```
img.forEach(function arrowFunction(img) {
  img.addEventListener('click', function mdl() {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
    modalImg.src = this.src;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NodeList.prototype.forEach` is a somewhat new method, only supported by newer browsers. It's not only IE that won't understand it - it took until Chrome 51 and FF 50 (mid-2016) to be implemented.

Use `.call` on `Array.prototype.forEach` instead (and since `img` is a collection, probably call it `imgs`, plural, not `img` singular, to make the code more readable):

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  imgs,
  function(img) {
    img.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = 'block';
      modalImg.src = img.src;
    };
  }
);
```

Or use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach):

```
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
```

Of course you can also use a `for` loop to iterate instead, but they're ugly IMO - using `forEach` looks a lot cleaner.

Live snippet which should work on IE:

```js
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}

var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img[src]');
imgs.forEach(function(img) {
  img.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
    modalImg.src = img.src;
  };
});
```

```html
<div id="modal">
  <img id="modalImg">
</div>

<div style="border: 1px solid black"></div>

<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/1653262911/picture?type=large">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfbzj.png?s=32&g=1">
```

Comment: I agree the forEach() looks better now if I'm understanding this correctly I can just implement the polyfill into the actual function its self like any other if statement and it would solve the issue?

Comment: Right, just make sure to run the silly-simple "polyfill" before where you use `NodeList.prototype.forEach`.

Comment: this might sound dumb but before? so the imgs.forEach() should be inside the polyfill?

Comment: No, just before, eg `<polyfill> \n imgs.forEach(...`

Comment: So I can't really see what I could have done wrong here since you basically did it for me (thanks by the way) 
so I have the the Polyfill then just below it the imgs.forEach but in IE it still isn't working.

Comment: There is no error message it's when i changed the code to match and then refresh it in the live server and click an image nothing is happening but it does work in chrome still.

Comment: I edited a live snippet into the question, and it looks to run just fine on IE, image changes as desired, no errors

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to help me with this thank you. that snippet did work. then i checked the console is IE and realize I had other function that were using es6 arrow functions as well so I had to comment them out. I guess a 10hr work day and now 3 hours of studying is too much for my brain.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `img` is a `NodeList` or `HTMLCollection`, you can also just go back to a basic `for` loop which works with any `NodeList` or `HTMLCollection` in IE:

```
for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
  img[i].addEventListener('click', function mdl() {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
    modalImg.src = this.src;
  })
}
```

If this doesn't work, then please tell us what `img` actually is or show us the code that sets that variable so we can see for ourselves what it is.

Also, you may want to insert `console.log(...)` into the click event listener so you can see if it's actually firing or not.

FYI, it's rare to see people still coding for IE.  That's soon going to be a dying skill (very few people who can or will do it).

Comment: Thank you for the response and yes I'm using the document.querySelectorAll in order to define imgs

Comment: @Brandon.b - Why does your code refer to `img` when your comment say `imgs`?  Is there something wrong there?  Show us more code and HTML and we're more likely to be able to help.

Comment: well considering this is a project I'm hosting on GH pages for my portfolio i assumed it would be a good idea to have it function properly in all browsers.

Comment: @Brandon.b - IE is pretty much not used by consumers any more, only by people in enterprises who have to use it for really old enterprise web apps that have not kept up with the times.  What version of IE are you targeting?  The population of home or enterprise users (that you would actually care about) that are still using IE is near zero.  On my own web app/site, I would spend my time enhancing the site and making it more valuable for regular browsers rather than making it work with IE.  The testing alone with IE is a lot of work and a big distraction from more valuable work.

Comment: So based on this I've pretty much wasted time for everyone.. lol... well that's a bummer. sorry guys hahah. now at least I know.